# jQuery data() is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-data

In my following code:

```
addUserHandler: function () {
    var $user = this.$('#user');
    if (($user.val().length > 0) && ($user.val() === $user.data('name'))) {
        this.addUser($user.data());                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    } 
    $user.val('');
    return false;
}
```

When I add the first user and then if I select another user from the `autocomplete` text field, it actually replaces the previously selected item's data with the new one. So always all the previously selected items will be replaced with the final one.

I'm using jQuery 2.0 and this issue started to occur after I updated from jQuery 1.9.

Anyone know any recent changes that jQuery has done for `$.data()`  I tried to find some proper solutions, but couldn't found any.

Thanks

Comment: IDs are unique, so there can only be one `$('#user')`.

Comment: What is this: `var $user = this.$('#user');`,  That doesn't look right to me.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
var $user = this.$('#user');
```

to

```
var $user = $(this).find('#user');
```

or simply

```
var $user = $('#user');// it must be unique
```

Comment: Which `browser` you are using?

Comment: Chrome Version 29.0.1547.57 m

Answer (score 0):

`var $user = this.$('#user');` this value stays same and wherever u use it that's y it shows up the same value...